# Error while reading xlsm file by Pandas : "Conditional Formatting extension is not supported"

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, readfile, xlsm

I want to read a xlsm file by Pandas:

```
pd.read_excel("data.xlsm", engine='openpyxl', sheet_name="sheet1")
```

But, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_read_only.py:79: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  for idx, row in parser.parse():
C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_read_only.py:79: UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
  for idx, row in parser.parse():
```

Another try: I saved the data file by xlsx format and tried to read that by:

```
pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", engine='openpyxl', sheet_name="sheet1")
```

And this time, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28028\1689108907.py", line 1, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(data_original_filepath, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=sheet_name)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1419, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 525, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 518, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 536, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 278, in read
    self.read_workbook()

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 150, in read_workbook
    self.parser.parse()

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\workbook.py", line 49, in parse
    package = WorkbookPackage.from_tree(node)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 83, in from_tree
    obj = desc.from_tree(el)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in from_tree
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in <listcomp>
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

In fact, I have to read the xlsm file. Changing the format to xlsx was only for trial purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this block of code.

```
import openpyxl
file='data.xlsm'
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I get the same error for both xlsx & xlsm files. Do you know the reason that I get this error? Is there any issue with the dataset itself?